# Auto ingress with contour

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am using `k8s` to deploy `spark` invoked using `spark-submit`. We use `contour` as our `ingress-class`. I was wondering if there is way to create `ingress` object for the `spark-driver` container to expose **Spark UI**. I am trying to see if all this can be done in one step process may be by using `annotations` or `labels`. Something like [hxquangnhat/kubernetes-auto-ingres](https://github.com/hxquangnhat/kubernetes-auto-ingress)s, which uses `annotation` to enable `ingress`

All I want to do is to use `spark-submit` to submit the `spark` job and get the **Spark UI** exposed. May be create the `ingress` using `--conf` like

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/scrape=true \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.annotation.prometheus.io/scrape=true \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/port=XXXXX \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.annotation.prometheus.io/port=XXXXX \
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts or have seen some examples like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create Ingress right after Spark Driver submission. Simply provide a script with a language of your choice having Kubernetes client library.

In order to configure automatic Ingress deletion/GC on Spark Driver Pod deletion you can use [Kubernetes OwnerReference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents) to Spark Driver Pod.

Also you may want to refer the Apache Livy project [Spark on Kubernetes support PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/pull/167) and the related [Helm charts repo](https://github.com/jahstreet/spark-on-kubernetes-helm), which offer a way to solve Spark UI exposure as well as some other aspects of running Spark on Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks Aliakasandra. That what I also thought. I was trying to see if there is anything other method available